# Unable to import submodules of scipy in AWS Lambda

Tags: python, scipy, aws-lambda

I have imported several packages into my `AWS Lambda python code`. I have `scipy` installed and seems to be imported correctly using `import scipy`.However, when I try to import the submodules like `from scipy.signal import lfilter` , I am unable to import those kind of modules in the `Lambda` function. I have no clue on why the package import works `locally` and not on `Lambda`

Here is a my worker.py

```
import logging

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = urllib.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']).decode('utf8')

    runFunction(bucket, key)

    try:
        response = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
        print("CONTENT TYPE: " + response['ContentType'])
        return response['ContentType']
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Here is my handler.py

```
import sys
try:
  import numpy as np
  print(1)
  import pandas as pd
  print(2)
  from scipy.signal import lfilter
  print(3)
  from uts import io, utils
except Exception, err:
print Exception, err

runFunction(bucket, key)
```

In this code, I am not able to import `from scipy.signal import lfilter`. Printing 1 and 2 is fine but the third print statement doesn't work and throws exception.

Here is the exception.

> libblas.so.3: cannot open shared object
>   file: No such file or directory

Comment: How are you deploying your packages to Lambda?

Comment: I am zipping the entire source with all the required dependency package folders.

Comment: I have numpy and I am able to use that. However, with scipy I am not.

Comment: Maybe create sample code to show us? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Did you build the source packages on a compatible Linux system?

Comment: I have built it on the AMI what AWS suggested. I have several projects where I am using numpy and those lambda function work fine. The problem is with scipy